# Am I understanding this circuit right?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, iphone

This is from an iPhone 6. I'm having a hard time understanding how q1701 controls the "handshake" to Tristar_pin to allow charging. (Diagram says "pin for handshake" next to C1704 at top right.)

I don't see anything controlling the gate of q1701 either. Am I right to assume current flow that I've traced in red?

[image]

Comment: Please post a clearer png, this is unreadable

Comment: @laptop2d It's a screen shot from my phone. Looks clear until I upload it. Idk why

Comment: Probably cropping...

Comment: If I show entire circuit it looks even worse. Is there a way to post it better from just a screen shot from phone?

Comment: "q1401 controls the "handshake" to Tristar_pin to allow charging" - says who? "I don't see anything controlling the gate of q1401" - I don't even see a q1401...

Comment: Sorry I meant q1701 I've edited original post

Answer (score 0):

If "Tristar pin" (which appears to be what it says on diagram) is taken high then the P Channel MOSFET (which the diagram shows that it is ) is turned on as it is P Channel (according to diagram) and then has gate low and source high. A greater issue is that IF the pin is tristated then the FET state is undefined - but arguably that's not a problem as it does or doesn't connect the output to a tristated pin. If the pin is low then the FET is off and the output is high impedance (which may be termed tri-stated depending on their nomenclature).

The FET MAY also be one of

CSD68822F4 TLV70518YFPR TPS62698YFDR TPS826745SIPT

IF the chart [**here**](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Texas%20Instruments/PCN20160610005.pdf) means what it appears to mean.

[image]