# Understanding the operation of a grounded gate P-channel MOSFET in a iPhone 6 charger

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

In the circuit below Q1701 is part of a charging circuit in an iPhone 6.

Since there are no datasheets available for the main components in the circuit I've been trying to figure out the operation.

With a charger disconnected:

- S = 0V
- G = 0V
- D = 0V

Charger connected:

- S = 5V
- G = 4.29V
- D = 5V

So this is where it leaves me confused, if a P-channel MOSFET turns on when it sees 0V at the gate (which I thought was the reason R1710 has it connected to ground) how is it turning on with 4.29V at the gate?

[image: Part of the schematic]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258293/am-i-understanding-this-circuit-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Charger connected:
>
> S = 5v G = 4.29v D = 5v

How do you get G = 4.3 V? The gate is connected directly to ground, and the gate-source diode is reverse biased so it plays no role. The gate will be at 0 V here. (Unless there's something else connected to the REVERSE_GATE node that you haven't shown in the schematics you shared)

> if a P-channel mosfet turns on when it sees 0v at the gate

A P-channel (enhancement mode) MOSFET turns on when it sees a gate-source voltage more negative than its threshold voltage.

The voltage relative to the circuit reference (ground) is irrelevant.

From comments,

> why even have that mosfet if it's always going to conduct having the gate at ground? What's the benefit

This is a reverse protection circuit.

Note that current will normally flow from drain to source, rather than the usual direction for PMOS of source to drain. This gets the body diode oriented the right way for a reverse protection circuit.

Now if you accidentally reverse the power supply, you'd be connecting the drain to -5 V. Then Vgs will be positive and the FET will not conduct; also the body diode will be reverse biased and will not conduct. This prevents any power being delivered to the rest of the circuit, so it won't be damaged.

Comment: There are no other netlists for "reverse_gate" on the entire schematic. My only guess is maybe that net goes to the USB cable itself? So you're saying as long as the voltage at the gate is lower than the source it will turn on? Even if only a few milivolts lower?

Comment: If V_gs is more negative than the threshold voltage, it will (start to) turn on. If V_gs is just a few millivolts negative, it likely won't pass more than a few nanoamps of leakage current.

Comment: That's strange then, how can the design be of any substantial use?

Comment: But in this case, Vgs should be about -5 V, so I don't see why you're worried about the "just a few millivolts" question.

Comment: The design is useful because Vg = 0 and Vs = 5 V, so Vgs = -5 V.

Comment: So gate voltage is not really 4.3v I measured but -4.3v?

Comment: The gate is connected to ground through R1710. I would expect the gate voltage to be 0 V. When you measured 4.3 V, are you sure the other lead of the meter was at ground?

Comment: Yes positive the other lead was at ground

Comment: You're sure the meter was in voltage mode, not diode mode?

Comment: Yes because I was taking other voltage measurements at the same time

Comment: I see three possibilities: 1. You did the measurement wrong. 2. The schematics you have are wrong (I assume these are reverse engineered, who knows by who). 3. The circuit you're testing is broken.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, why even have that mosfet if it's always going to conduct having the gate at ground? What's the benefit

Comment: Based on the schematic, Vg will be 0 V when Vs is 5 V, and the FET will conduct. The benefit is reverse protection. If the drain is at -5 V, then it will not conduct and the rest of the circuit won't be damaged.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks a lot! Really helped me out with this. Also I just rechecked and the area is so tiny my meter probe was accidentally touching the top of the mosfet mosfet which doesn't have a black coating so it was reading the voltage directly across it

Comment: One more question, PP5V0_USB is coming from PP_TRISTAR__PIN correct? Not the other way around?

Comment: My guess is PP5V0_USB is coming from the USB connector and PP_TRISTAR_PIN is going to the rest of the circuit. That way the body diode is reverse biased when there's a reverse voltage connection. In normal operation, the body diode is possibly conducting, but after start up the channel shorts it out anyway.

Comment: If that's the case how can the source of the mosfet be higher than the gate for it to conduct if the voltage is coming from the drain side?

Comment: 1. The MOSFET (leaving aside the body diode) is a symmetrical device. It can turn on from Vgd the same as from Vgs. 2. When power is first applied, the body diode will conduct, bringing the source up to Vd - 0.7 or so, then Vgs will be negative and the channel will turn on.

Comment: Ok thanks. Apple schematics can be confusing its hard to tell inputs from outputs on them

Comment: So going back to the reverse protection, the body diode would prevent that so is a possible reason they chose a mosfet rather than just a regular diode is for current handling capability or? Just curious why a regular diode wasn't used for protection

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum. If you want to chat, feel free to join the [EE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Answer (score 0):

Some p channel mosfets can turn on a reasonable amount with just a few hundred millivolts between source and gate. 0.7 volts doesn't sound unreasonable especially if the drain current is low. Try looking at Alpha Omega's offerings to see what is possible. The AOC2413 looks good in this respect.